# Problem with Runtime Process Execution

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Can somebody find what is wrong with this code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr;
File myFolder = new File("C:\\Temp");
pr = rt.exec("myExec.bat", null, myFolder);
pr.waitFor();
pr.destroy();
```

When I run this code, I get following exception (while file and folder used exist as specified):

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "myExec.bat" (in directory "C:\Temp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at com.radml.radmlp.main(Test.java:10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rt.exec expects a file with no path information to be in the user dir and not in the directory you specify to use as working directory. Using it this way

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr;
    File myFolder = new File("C:\\Temp");
    pr = rt.exec(new File(myFolder, "myExec.bat").getAbsolutePath(), null, myFolder);
    pr.waitFor();
    pr.destroy();
```

should work as long as your file c:\Temp\myExec.bat exists.

Greetz,
GHad

Comment: You are right GHad, I got your point and this resolves my above issue but now I am facing another problem. I am trying to run python file through java and getting following error: "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Temp\create-application.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application". Python is installed on my machine and I can run all ???.py on command prompt

Comment: Use "cmd /c C:\Temp\create-application.py" for the first rt.exec argument. This should work, else try "start C:\Temp\create-application.py". Greetz GHad

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that your bat file is located in "`C:\Temp\myExec.bat`"?

*(Just a guess, but make sure the file isn't actually called* `C:\Temp\myExec.bat`**`.txt`** *)*

Comment: Yes file and folders are correct and I can run it from command prompt